# ¿Cual seria el equivalente de file_get_contents($url) en JavaScript o TypeScript?

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic, ionic2

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con ionic 2 y quiero extraer unos datos de una pagina externa en otro dominio, y la forma como lo he solucionado es con `PHP` de la siguiente forma:

**miPhp.php**

```
    //$url = 'http://www.flalottery.com/fantasy5';
    $url = 'http://www.flalottery.com/exptkt/ff.html';
    $pagina = file_get_contents($url);
    echo  $pagina;
?>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public http:  Http ) {
     this.http.get('http://localhost/miPhp.php').subscribe(
       datos => console.log(datos._body))
  }
}
```

El archivo `php` esta ejecutándose en un servidor local apache.

**¿Como puedo hacer lo que hace el archivo `php` pero con `JavaSecript` o `TypeScript`?**

Comment: **importa la el framework o libreria Atoms.js
alli encontraras lo que buscas**

Comment: https://www.genbetadev.com/javascript/los-10-frameworks-librerias-mas-populares-de-javascript

**Esta página te ayudará**

Comment: Hola Rosa, estuve leyendo sobre Atoms.js y la verdad dudo que haga lo mismo que file_get_contents($url) y me podrias dar un ejemplo de como funciona esto te agradezco